# Android error when generating JSonStringer

Tags: android, arrays, json

I need to generate new **JSONStringer** using some key-value and one of them is an array of strings.

This is what the string should be like:

```
{"Array":[""],"UserID":Id,"Key":"key"}
```

Note that the array should contains one value for now
I am using the below to generate the **JSONStringer**:

```
       try {

            stringer = new JSONStringer()
                    .object()
                    .array().object().key("Array").value("value in the array")
                    .endObject().endArray()
                    .key("UserID").value("123")
                    .key("Key").value("abc")
                    .endObject();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it gives the exception nesting problem.

Comment: Post logs from the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
 try {
    String stringer = new JSONStringer()
        .object()
        .key("Array")
        .array().value("value in the array")
        .endArray()
        .key("UserID").value("123")
        .key("Key").value("abc")
        .endObject().toString();
    Log.d("mytag", "onCreate: " + stringer);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
D/mytag: onCreate: {"Array":["value in the array"],"UserID":"123","Key":"abc"}
```